# How to add json objects from file to another json array of objects in another file

Tags: python, json, bash, sed, jq

In *nix environment. I'm seeking a solution on how to add some (not quite so valid) json in a file, to another (valid) json file. Let me elaborate and also cover some failed attempts I've tried so far.

This will run in a shell script in a loop which will grow quite large. It's making an api call which can only return 1000 at a time. However, there are 70,000,000+ total records. So, I will have to make this api call 70,000 times in order to get all of the desired records. The original json file I want to keep, it includes information outside of the actual data I want, such as result info and success messages, etc. Each time I iterate and call the next set, I'm trying to strip out that information and just append the main data records to the main data records of the first set.

I'm already 99% there. I'm attempting this using `jq` `sed` and `python`. The body of the data records is not technically valid json. So `jq` is complaining because it can only append if valid data. My attempt looks like this `jq --argjson results "$(<new.json)" '.result[] += [$results]' original.json`. But if it would, then it would be valid json.

I've already used `grep -n` to abstract the line number of where I want to start appending the new sets of records to the first set of records. So I've been trying to use `sed` but can not figure out the right syntax. Though I feel I'm close. I've been trying something like `sed -i -e $linenumber '<a few sed things here> new.json' original.json`. But no success yet.

I've now tried to write a `python` script to do this. But I had never tried anything like this before. Just some string matching on readlines and string replacements. I didn't realize that there isn't a built in method for jumping to a specific line. I guess I could do some find statements to jump to that line in `python` but I've already done this in the bash script. Also, I realize I could read each line to memory in `python` but I fear that with this many records, it might get to be too much and become very slow.

I had some passing thoughts on trying some kind of `head` and `tail` and write in between since I know the exact line number. Any thoughts or solutions with any tools/languages are welcome. This is a devops project that is just to diagnose some logs, so I'm trying to not make this a full project, as once I produce the logs, I'll shift all my focus and efforts to running commands against this final produced json file and not really use this script ever again.

Example of `original.json`

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "5b5915f4cdb39c7b",
      "kind": "foo",
      "source": "bar",
      "action": "baz",
      "matches": [
        {
          "id": "b298ee91704b489b8119c1d604a8308d",
          "source": "blah",
          "action": "buzz"
        }
      ],
      "occurred_at": "date"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b5915f4cdb39c7b",
      "kind": "foo",
      "source": "bar",
      "action": "baz",
      "matches": [
        {
          "id": "b298ee91704b489b8119c1d604a8308d",
          "source": "blah",
          "action": "buzz"
        }
      ],
      "occurred_at": "date"
    }
],
  "result_info": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "dlipU4c",
      "before": "iLjx06u"
    },
    "scanned_range": {
      "since": "date",
      "until": "date"
    }
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}
```

Example of new.json

```
{
  "id": "5b5915f4cdb39c7b",
  "kind": "foo",
  "source": "bar",
  "action": "baz",
  "matches": [
    {
      "id": "b298ee91704b489b8119c1d604a8308d",
      "source": "blah",
      "action": "buzz"
    }
  ],
  "occurred_at": "date"
},
{
  "id": "5b5915f4cdb39c7b",
  "kind": "foo",
  "source": "bar",
  "action": "baz",
  "matches": [
    {
      "id": "b298ee91704b489b8119c1d604a8308d",
      "source": "blah",
      "action": "buzz"
    }
  ],
  "occurred_at": "date"
}
```

Don't worry about the indentation or missing trailing commas, I already have that figured out and confirmed working.

Comment: Does `jq --argjson results "[$(<new.json)]" '.result += $results' original.json` do what you want?

Comment: Also, file a bug report against whatever thinks `{...},{...}` is a reasonable thing to return.

Comment: It would, if it was valid json (i.e. `{...},{...}`), which it is not. So no, it's not working, it gives me an error, as it should, because it makes sense. It's not valid json. But if it did work, the result would be valid json. I think you misunderstood no where is saying `{...},{...}` is valid json.

Comment: I know it's not; that's why I wrapped `$(<new.json)` in `[...]` in my suggestion, to turn it into a valid array.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. And yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much @chepner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the invalid JSON from the API response into a valid array by wrapping it in `[...]`. The resulting array can be imported and added directly to the `result` array.

```
jq --argjson results "[$(<new.json)]" '.result += $results' original.json
```

Answer (score 0):

So first to add results into new file create a json file with "[]" an empty array as its content, this is to make sure the file we load is valid json.
Next run the following command for each file as input

```
jq --argjson results "$(<new.json)" '.result | . += $results  '  orig.json > new.json
```

Issue with your query was .result[] this return all the elements individually not as a json object in format

```
{}
{}
```

instead of

```
[
{},
{}
]
```

Comment: This originally got me, but I did fix this with sed to add the commas, which are included in the question. Which is also technically not valid json. With the comma between the two objects `jq` complains with Expecting 'EOF' which if you go to any online json validator and try, you will get the same. Which is why I had no success with `jq` either.

Comment: Actually when we specify .result it return json array object which is valid json

Comment: Hmm.... I just tried `jq --argjson results "$(<objects-with-commas.json)" '.result | . += $results ' orig.json > new.json`. The `orig.json` and `objects-with-commas.json` is exactly like file in two files from original question post above. I will get `jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson` from jq. My version is `jq-1.6` if that helps.

Comment: It should not have result_info..... It just have [ at start and ] at end added for it to be a valid json ...... Why are you using 3 files replace objects-with-commas json file with new.json and make sure new.json have "[]" as its file content dont include the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given new.json and its description, you seem to have comma-separated JSON objects with the JSON-separating commas on separate lines matching the regex '^}, *$'

If that's the case, the good news is you can achieve the result you want by simply removing the superfluous commas with:

```
sed 's/^}, *$/}/' new.txt
```

This produces a stream of objects, which can then be processed in any one of several well-known ways (e.g. by "slurping" it using the -s option).

#### "XY problem"?

In a side-comment, you wrote:

> I did fix this with sed to add the commas, which are included in the question.

So it is beginning to sound as if the Q as posted is really a so-called ["XY" problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Anyway, if you were starting with a stream of JSON objects, then of course there would be need to add the commas and deal with the consequences.